# Conexión a MySQL desde java

Tags: java

Buenas,

Estoy intentado conectarme a la MySQL desde java pero no lo consigo. Mi código es el siguiente:

Por una parte tengo la clase principal:

```
public class App {      
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    NetUtils.initProxy();

    Conectate con = new Conectate();

}
```

Y por otro la clase `Conectate()`:

```
public class Conectate {
   private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/XboxOne";
   private String pass = "";
   private String usuario = "root";
   public Connection con;

   public Conectate() {
     try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
    }

}

public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
   String Str="";
   if(Obj!=null){
     Str = Obj.toString();
   }
   return Str;
}


}
```

No encuentro la forma de solventar el problema. El error que me da es el siguiente: `DBjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Comment: ¿Qué hace NetUtils.initProxy()?

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente la excepción que tira? No es lo mismo credenciales inválidas, timeout o connection lost, etc.

Comment: @Dementor Perdón tienes razón, el error que me da es el siguiente `DBjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta el jar de mySQL, sin él no vas a poder realizar la conexión.

Si usas maven, añade la dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Si no, descarga el jar [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) y añádelo a tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema con el que me encuentro es que no tengo la carpeta "Libraries". Es el único método de los dos que comentas que se usar. Creo que tendría que usar el código que me facilitas pero no sé en qué parte. Tengo una carpeta de "Dependencies", otra de "Test Dependencies" y una última "Java Dependencies". Si hago click derecho me deja agregar otra dependencia pero hay que rellenar una serie de campos que no entiendo.

Comment: Esos campos son, o deberían ser, los que te he puesto en el caso de usar maven. Revisa tu proyecto y busca un fichero "pom.xml". En él habrá más entradas de tipo "<dependency>" como la que he copiado arriba.

Comment: Solucionado, ¡muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que deberias especificar que error te da java, el no poder conectarte puede ser por varias cosas, la contraseña, el paquete de sql sin importar etc...
Te paso una clase de conexion que suelo usar lo unico que tienes que cambiar es el nombre a la base de datos que se conecta el usuario y la contraseña

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

import constantes.ConstantesGlobales;



public class Conector {
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement prepareStatement;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Conector() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.conn = null;
    }
    //CONECTARSE A LA BBDD
    public void conectarBD(){
            try {
                Class.forName(ConstantesGlobales.DRIVER).newInstance();
                if (ConstantesGlobales.DRIVER.equals("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")){
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConstantesGlobales.URL,ConstantesGlobales.USER,ConstantesGlobales.PASSWD);
                }else{
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConstantesGlobales.URL); 
                }                           
            } catch (SQLException  | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }
    //DESCONECTARSE BBDD
    public void cerrarConexion(){
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //METODO PARA EJECUTAR QUERYS DE UPDATE
    public void ejecutarQueryUpdate(PreparedStatement preparedStatement){
        try {           
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //METODO PARA EJECUTAR CONSULTAS
    public ResultSet ejecutarQuery(String sql){
        try {
            prepareStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet resulset = prepareStatement.executeQuery(sql);
            return resulset;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    //METODO PARA CERRAR EL PREPARESTATEMENT QUE SE QUEDA ABIERTO EN EL METODO "ejecutarQuery()"
    public void closeStatement(){
        try {
            prepareStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //GETERS Y SETERS
    public Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }
    public void setConn(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }


}
```

Como tengo algunos literales en la clase de constantes globales te la paso tambien

```
package constantes;

public class ConstantesGlobales {
    public static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    public static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/01proyectoadat";
    public static final String USER = "root";
    public static final String PASSWD = "admin";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No he podido comprobarlo porque me da un problema de multi-catch excepción y no me deja cambiar la versión del JDK. No sé si hay otra forma de ponerlo. Esta es la línea que me da error `catch (SQLException  | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e)`

Comment: Has añadido la libreria con el `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin` al proyecto?

Comment: Sí, está ya solucionado el problema, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que colocaste un patrón en tu `cadenaConexión`. Si tienes tu mysql corriendo en la misma maquina donde ejecutas el código y no cambiaste el puerto por defecto, lo siguiente te debería funcionar:

```
private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
// o 
private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/XboxOne";
```

asumiendo que tu `host` es localhost (o 127.0.0.1), el puerto por defecto y la base de datos `XboxOne`.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Ya lo había probado pero tampoco me ha resuelto el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pego a continuación el código de la clase que yo uso para conectarme a una base de datos mysql desde java.

```
    package clasesmias;

    import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
    import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
     *
     * @author juany
    */
    public class Conexion {
    /*
     * Conexion():Constructor, realiza la conexion a la base de datos
     *
     * cierraConexion(): cierra la conexion a la base de datos
    */
      public Byte error;
      public Connection conexion;
      public Statement instruc;
      public boolean autoCommit = true;
    public Conexion(){
           error = 0;
           conexion = null;
           instruc = null;
           /*Config conf = new Config();
          if (conf.error != 0){
               error = 1;
               return;
           }*/
          try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = (Connection)        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdescuela1","root","contraseña");
        //conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(conf.ubicacionBase,conf.usuarioBase,conf.claveBase);
        instruc = (Statement) conexion.createStatement();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        error = 1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return;
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        error = 1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        error = 1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}

public void cierraConexion(){
    error = 0;
    try {
        conexion.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        error = 1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        //Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo he probado pero me sigue dando el siguiente error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Pero tenes agregada la libreria mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar a tu proyecto???